# Spring Integration Jms InboundGateway Dynamic Reply Queue

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to have a dynamic reply queue with `Jms OutboundGateway` via DSL?

```
Jms.inboundGateway(jmsListenerContainer)
    .defaultReplyQueueName("queue1 or queue2")
```

**Working Solution using ThreadLocal and DestinationResolver:**

```
private static final ThreadLocal<String> REPLY_QUEUE = new ThreadLocal<>();

IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.inboundGateway(listenerContainer)
                         .defaultReplyQueueName("defaultQueue1")
                         .destinationResolver(destinationResolver())
                .transform(p -> {
                    // on some condition, else "defaultQueue1"
                    REPLY_QUEUE.set("changedToQueue2");
                    return p;
                })

@Bean
public DestinationResolver destinationResolver() {
        
    return (session, destinationName, pubSubDomain) -> session.createQueue(REPLY_QUEUE.get());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from where you'd like to take that dynamic reply queue name, but there is another option:

```
/**
 * @param destinationResolver the destinationResolver.
 * @return the spec.
 * @see ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener#setDestinationResolver(DestinationResolver)
 */
public S destinationResolver(DestinationResolver destinationResolver) {
```

By default this one is a `DynamicDestinationResolver` which does only this: `return session.createQueue(queueName);`. Probably here you can play somehow with your different names to determine.

Another way is to have a `JMSReplyTo` property set in the request message from the publisher.

**UPDATE**

Since you cannot rely on a default `Reply-To` JMS message property, I suggest you to look into a `ThreadLocal` in your downstream flow where you can place your custom header. Then a custom `DestinationResolver` can take a look into that `ThreadLocal` variable for a name to delegate to the same mentioned `DynamicDestinationResolver`.

Comment: Was planning to decide the destination based on a custom Jms header. The producer of the (request) message is a legacy system, hence trying to find a way around. Can we get access to the Jms headers via the `DynamicDestinationResolver`? please suggest.

Comment: Do you think it is OK to use a `MessageSourceMutator` and then create a new message with `JMSReplyTo` header? Are the headers Immutable in `MessageSourceMutator` too?

Comment: The `MessageSourceMutator` has nothing to do with the `JmsInboundGateway` which is essentially a message-driven channel adapter not source polling.

Comment: You can't do it through the DSL, but the gateway itself uses a `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener` you might be able subclass that and override `onMessage` and then set the `replyTo` on the inbound message based on the header (then call the superclass) - I am not sure if that is a mutable property on an inbound message (might depend on the provider), so you might have to create a new message from the actual message.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: I think we can improve that component and have a `replyToExpression` to be able to resolve that value against `jakarta.jms.Message` root object.

Comment: Thanks Artem and Gary, I shall try the valuable suggestions shared.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3957 submitted for a feature request

Comment: Thanks Artem, `ThreadLocal` and `DestinationResolver` worked for us. Can you please take look at the snippet of the same posted to see if it is OK? Also, where could be the one place I can invoke `remove()` on the `ThreadLocal`

Comment: I guess the best place is your custom `DynamicDestinationResolver` just after reading that `ThreadLocal` value!